# Django ForeignKey getting results

Tags: python, django, web

I've tried following other questions but I'm still having some problems.

I have 2 models:

```
class Media(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    media = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=MEDIA_TYPE)

class Review(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    media = models.ForeignKey(Media, related_name='rev_media')
```

I want to go do something like

```
blaw = Media.objects.all()
for a in blaw:
    print (all the reviews to have to do with this one media object)
```

Comment: have you checked the docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/

Comment: I'm trying to follow the "Following relationships “backward”" part but struggling on how to sort each entry.

Comment: Following it gives me 'Media' object has no attribute 'review_set'

Comment: why not just follow their tutorial, using their code examples? You can change the names after, and "books" and "authors" are not so different to media and review?

Comment: their example is "b.entry_set.all()" - did you call _set.all()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a `related_name`, you can use `a.rev_media.all()` to get the list of associated objects.

Now, you can do:

```
media_qs = Media.objects.all()
for media in media_qs:
    reviews = media.rev_media.all() #basically, this is the queryset of all the associated reviews for this media object.
    if reviews.exists():

        print ", ".join([review.message for review in reviews])
```

Comment: This worked thanks. I just couldn't seem to pull it off.

Comment: Glad it helped. The documentation on the reverse relationships in the djangodocs is not very elaborate, I agree !!

Answer (score 0):

`rev_media`, your related_name, should give you all the reviews that have it as a foreign key:

```
blaw = Media.objects.all()
for a in blaw:
    print media.rev_media.all()
```

Comment: Nope. (even after changing media to a (and just in case a.media.review_set)) I get: 'Media' object has no attribute 'review_set'

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you have a related_name.  How about what it says now?

Comment: Ah, the other answer has that.  That one is correct.